# bug when rotating vectors, creating new vectors with adjust rotation

Tags: javascript, math, vector, rotation, trigonometry

I'm having a strange bug in the following code. Scroll down to see images for reference to this question. The program found in the images below is drawn in canvas using javascript, so please be aware that the x and y coordinates are all positive, so the y coordinates are upside down relative to the graph.

```
let rotateVectors = (vs, t) => {
      return sortVectors(Object.keys(vs).map(v => {

        console.log(vs[v].vector.direction);
        let rateOfRotation = -.01 * (Math.random() * (5-1)+1);
        let vector = vs[v].vector
        let p = vector.magnitude;
        let c = vector.coords;
        let x = c.x*Math.cos(rateOfRotation) - c.y*Math.sin(rateOfRotation);
        let y = c.x*Math.sin(rateOfRotation) + c.y*Math.cos(rateOfRotation);
        return vector(cartesian2dCoordinate(x,y))
      }));
    }
```

**The above method is called on a loop to slowly rotate vectors by some random amount**, the map function returns a **new vector** which takes an x,y coordinate, or the 2d cartesian pair describing the rise and run of the vector.

rotateVectors returns a sorted list of all vectors (**sorted by angle in degrees**) in the vs object.

```
let vectorDirection = (c) => {
  //THE ZERO VECTOR
  if(c.x === 0 && c.y === 0) return 0;

  //cardinal directions, vertical and horizontal
  else if(c.x === 0) return c.y > 0 ? .5 : 1.5;
  else if(c.y === 0) return c.x > 0 ? 0:Math.PI;

  //q3
  else if(c.x< 0 && c.y < 0) return (1+ (Math.atan(-1*((c.y * -1) / c.x))));
  //q2
  else if(c.x < 0 && c.y > 0) return (Math.PI / 180)*(180 + toDegrees(Math.atan((c.y * -1)/c.x)));
  //q4
  else if(c.y < 0 && c.x > 0) return  (Math.PI / 180)*(toDegrees(Math.atan((c.y * -1)/c.x)));
  //q1
  else return Math.atan(c.y*-1/c.x);
}
```

This function returns a radian of the angle of a vector based on its quadrant.

[Traversal zone 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOEhl.png)

In image one, any given vector will rotate from the x plane marked in red, all the way around to the -y vertical column. S->E.

[traversal zone 2, reversed direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bM0W.png)

In image two, the vector magically teleports from the E plane to the S plane, and travels in the opposite direction. S->E, whereupon the vector teleports back to the -X plane "S" in image1.

I'm relatively new to drawing stuff with vectors. I remember a bit of trig from school, but I haven't used it in a very long time. Does anyone have an idea wwhat may be happening here? Why are my vectors teleporting, changing direction, and why do no vectors travers the null zone to the left of S of image 2, and down from S of image 1?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Skp5O

null zone image. no vectors traverse this sector of the graph.

Comment: you should use the atan2 function in vectorDirection instead of having a case for each quadrant

Comment: Wow.... holy damn. I swear to God I tried atan2 all last night, but nothing happened. It works now as expected.

Comment: Good to hear it's working now. So, problem solved? May as well delete the question if there's nothing else. Or else you can self-answer

Comment: sure thing. i'll answer it.

Comment: Because atan takes y/x as a parameter, it can't tell the difference between the case where x and y are both positive and where they are both negative because y/x will be the same. It also can't tell the difference between where x is negative and y is positive and where x is positive and y is negative. So it can't determine the quadrant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to samgak for the answer in the comments. I replaced the original vectorDirection function with this code. It works as expected. Vectors rotate in the direction expected, and at the rate expected.

```
let vectorDirection = (c) => {
//THE ZERO VECTOR
  if(c.x === 0 && c.y === 0) return undefined;
  else return Math.atan2(-1*c.y,c.x)

}
```